# Element is not clickable(x,y) even there is no scroll in page have tried thread.sleep()

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to click on the "Login" button provided in the header I am new to selenium, here is the code snippet

```
public class Muft_Mashwara_login {

    public WebDriver driver= null;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void startBrowser () {
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://sqa.muftmashwara.be.vteamslabs.com/home");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } 

    @Test
    public void Click()throws InterruptedException {
        //Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header2']/nav/div/ul/li/a")).click();
        WebElement loginTxt = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/main/div/section/article[2]/div/div/form[1]/div[1]/div/input"));
        loginTxt.sendKeys("test@test.com");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void  Close() {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

It only works if I uncomment "Thread.sleep". I don't know how to implement dynamic wait in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work with something like this:

```
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5); // Wait up to five seconds. 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
    By.xpath(".//*[@id='header2']/nav/div/ul/li/a"))).click();

// Or perhaps:
//webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
//    By.xpath("//xpath"))).click();
```

You may also want to add this one before clicking, as the loading overlay interferes with clicking for some versions of webdriver.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(
    By.xpath("//div[@id='cover']")));
```

Comment: not working at all you can execute my code with your solution may be some glitch you will be able to find

Answer (score 0):

I think the webdriverwait is not working correctly for this scenario so Thread.sleep will do.

Try this code, it ran sucessfully at my end. 
And always Use Css before you think of XPath. 
Css are faster than Xpath.

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException, AWTException{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://sqa.muftmashwara.be.vteamslabs.com/home");
    Thread.sleep(10000L);
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".fa.fa-lock")).click();
}
```

Comment: With Thread.Sleep() I was able to execute it successfully, I don't want to use static wait

Comment: driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
public class Muft_Mashwara_login {

 public WebDriver driver= null;


    @BeforeMethod
    public void startBrowser () {

        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://sqa.muftmashwara.be.vteamslabs.com/home");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    } 

    @Test
    public void Click()throws InterruptedException {            

        //use javascript click here
        WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li>a[href='/login']"));
        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elem);

        WebElement loginTxt = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.form-group.ng-invalid>input[name='username']"));
        loginTxt.click();
        loginTxt.sendKeys("test@test.com");

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void  Close() {
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

but if u want to learn how to use dynamic wait,see the below example:

```
WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("ue selector")));

//u can use by xpath or class or name here also
// this will until the element is visible to the page
```